# max-allowed-packet error in sql while fetching data from Google API and batch insert

Tags: java, mysql, json, jdbc, max-allowed-packet

I have this error while inserting batch in mysql:

```
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Packet for query is too large (70,566,811 > 67,108,864). You can change this value on the server by setting the 'max_allowed_packet' variable.
```

I need to read the insights from a Google-API day by day and save them using [fetchMultiDailyMetricsTimeSeries Method](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/performance/rest/v1/locations/fetchMultiDailyMetricsTimeSeries). Everyday, the program should get executed to read the info related to 3 days ago,but I discovered that Google is not updated for last three days and **Now** I am obligated to update the info in my table for at least 3 months. Here arise the problem that we receive loads of data on a field typed JSON in `mysql` returned from API. So, I cannot change the table structure since there are other programs reading from this table and this problem will be no longer valid after updating the table.

The query is a simple Insert that I need to to consider `ON DUPLICATE UPDATE`. In fact, I cannot change the `max-allowed-pocket` variable (The ***DBA*** does not want to change it).

I have split my list in a way that for every 500 records, the program goes to do the insert. However, it seems that it is not enough and the received data is too large even in 500 records limit. right now, I am trying to make the break-point smaller and also fetch the info for a shorter loop of days like 10 so that there would not be a problem but this would be too slow since I need to perform these for all the clients (more than 20) and for 90 days.

I use `JAVA` and `JDBC Prepared Statement`.

What can I do else?

Comment: Nothing, really. If you bump into the packet size limot, then either you have to increase the limit or dexrease the size of the data you send.

Comment: Is your organization financially impacted by this inability to process data someone is providing for your consumption?  If so, share this reality with the DBA and maybe he will consider taking it to the limit of 1G.  If RAM is available on the server.  HTOP or TOP provides clues on RAM availability and usage for most Linux type systems..  Windows has similar clues.

Comment: @WilsonHauck Thank you,  This problem does not happen too often, after we migrated to new google API for reading the insights, I considered like the old API a delay of 72 hours but seemingly new API is more than 5 days late so I am obligated to update my database values for at least 3 months which leads to this much info. Right now I have just broke down the number of records to save and once updated for all the clients there wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: The very best always.  For performance tuning, view profile info.

Comment: Are you generating the input string in Java?  Can you stop before hitting the 64KB limit?  Or change the configuration if you will not exceed the hard limit of 1MB

Comment: @RickJames,  I am doing the split before reaching the limit, I was wondering if there is another way t tackle the issue but seems that there is no other method.

Comment: typo:  the hard limit is 1GB.